# ngClass animation failing when targetting child element

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

I don't understand why the animation here isn't working:
http://plnkr.co/edit/ulq1MQNDtY9cO2pcjdzF?p=preview

What should happen is:

- on add class: grow from `0` to `200px` and have the background color transition from `red` to `blue`
- on remove class: shrink from `200px` to `0` and have the background color transition from `green` to `yellow`

Any idea why?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are saying the animation does not work
The problem is that you are adding animation to '.heading', but you are toggling '.expanded' only.

Css animation will apply only when class is added, so removing the class and adding the class will activate the animation.

The following code will fix ur animation

```
<div class="container" ng-class="{expanded:isVisible}">
  <h1 ng-class="{heading:isVisible}">Hello Plunker!</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: I need to toggle the class on the parent and have other children react as well. The Plunkr is a simplified example.

Comment: Also, CSS transitions work on child elements when parent classes are added or removed. It's an ngAnimate issue.